# Apache Batik SVG to PDF - Output PDF is Incorrect Size

Tags: java, pdf, svg, pdfbox, batik

I'm trying to convert an `SVG` file into a `PDF` for embedding into another `PDF` document. I'm using the batik transcoder, passing in the bytes for the `SVG` and getting the data for the `PDF` back.

My main PDF document and the `SVG` file passed into the transcoder both have dimensions of:

```
width="602.8" height="763.8"
```

The output `PDF` file generated from the `SVG` is smaller however. Because of this, when embedded into our main document, the generated `SVG` PDF doesn't take up all available space in our main PDF as I would expect it to because it has smaller dimensions. How can I force the output pdf to have the same dimensions of the main document / input `SVG`.

Comment: pdf will renders in 72 dpi, but the is pdf format is vector. so, you can resize it. quality will be same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some further research I came to a solution. We're using PDFBox as our pdf manipulation tool which uses a DPI of 72 by default for documents.

Batik on the other hand uses a DPI of 96 when transcoding an SVG to a PDF file. This makes the output file slightly smaller than the main PDFBox generated document. To switch Batik to a DPI that supports PDFBox by default we must change the pixel to mm conversion from 96dpi to 72dpi.

We can add a transcoding hint to our PDFTranscoder as follows:

```
transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PDFTranscoder.KEY_PIXEL_UNIT_TO_MILLIMETER,
(25.4f / 72f));
```

where (25.4f / 72f) is equal to 72dpi. This will replace the default dpi of 96dpi (25.4f / 96f)